# pip install MySQLdb -t で出力したファイル郡をひとつのファイルにまとめ、importで読み取りたいです。(import mysql.MySQLdbみたいなイメージです。)

Tags: python, pip

`$ pip install MySQLdb -t .`

↑で出力されたMySQL周りのファイルを

`mysql/`
というディレクトリ内にいれて、かつ、
importでパッケージ?(ライブラリ)を読み取れるようにしたいです。

こういうイメージです。

├── mysql
│   ├── MySQL_python-1.2.5.egg-info
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   ├── installed-files.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   ├── MySQLdb
│   │   ├── **init**.py
│   │   ├── **init**.pyc
│   │   ├── connections.py
│   │   ├── connections.pyc
│   │   ├── constants
│   │   │   ├── CLIENT.py
│   │   │   ├── CLIENT.pyc
│   │   │   ├── CR.py

`単純に pip install MySQLdb とするだけではだめでして、仕様上どうしてもディレクトリ内にファイルを吐き出す方法を取らなくては行けません。`

また、カレントディレクトリに吐き出すだけでなく、mysqlというディレクトリにまとめた理由としましては、
他のプロジェクトでも使う際に、まとまっていた方が便利なためです。
（モジュールみたいに、一つの独立した形で再利用したいです。）

このような状況下の中、importしようと思っても上手くいきません。

> > > import mysql.MySQLdb
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

そもそもこういうことができるのかどうかわからず、色々と調べているのですが、
求めている記事に遭遇できなかったため、質問させて頂きました。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

まず `mysql` 下に、 `__init__.py` というファイルを追加します。中身は空で構いません。
これは `mysql` をモジュールとして認識させるために必要です。

次に、`mysql` を検索パスに追加します。

```
import sys
sys.path.append('mysql')
```

カレントディレクトリが異なる場合は、適宜　`'mysql'` を変更するか、絶対パスで指定してください。

以下も参照してください。
[Python チュートリアル - 6.4. パッケージ](http://docs.python.jp/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)